# How many months do you have to move to Canada if you get awarded an IEC visa?

Tags: canada

My boyfriend and myself are just about to complete the International Experience Canada application but we are hesitant because we aren't looking to go to Canada for another 10 months. If we are successful and get awarded a visa, do we have a certain amount of time in which to go to Canada?

Comment: According to http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/iec/after.asp, "Your POE [port of entry] Letter of Introduction will have a clearly marked expiry date. You must present your letter at a Canadian port of entry on or before this date to receive your work permit. Note: The expiry date of the POE Letter of Introduction cannot be changed or extended under any circumstance...." But there's no indication of what that date will be.

Answer (score 1):

There's some information [this FAQ](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=846&top=25):

> **For International Experience Canada (IEC) participants only:** Your Letter of Introduction will normally be valid for 12 months. If you
>   underwent a medical exam, it will be valid until the expiry date of
>   your medical exam or for 12 months, whichever is less. When you enter
>   Canada, the officer will give you a work permit that will be valid for
>   the time allowed by the agreement between Canada and your country. If,
>   on arrival, you did not receive the total time you are entitled to as
>   per your country agreement, you will be allowed to extend your work
>   permit for a time period that adds up to – but does not exceed – the
>   maximum allocated time for your country.